# Move div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really can't do a little thing. I want that div1 change it's position ON CLICK of `div2` (note that `div2` is inside of `div1`) and when clicking again div2, put div 1 to his original position. (If you could help me moving the div1 with a little animation it would be perfect).

I added my exemple to jsfiddle, where I want to change the "switcher"'s position on first click on "switcher-header", and when click second time "switcher-header" take "switcher" back to it's original position.

http://jsfiddle.net/mdx7dpeL/3/

Comment: You first need to include jQuery, and secondly, you animating `.color-default` but you don't have an element with that class.

Comment: .color default was a mistake, I updated the link :)

Comment: This is not really a problem, its a "Please program X for me" type of question

Comment: Okay, I code a whole template, it was done and I needed just this thing, because I am not familiar with jquery, but before do that I lost hours searching on google and trying to do it, but never was how I wanted to be. And what are you talking about? This is a community to help each other and not to make idiot comments like you.

Comment: I am sorry if this comes out as rude but check this out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions If something like this is really a problem for you, you should really start by first learning jQuery or DHTML in general and then doing it. I am sorry to hear that you lost sevaral hours google-ing, but you should have checked out [http://api.jquery.com/animate/](jQuery's own API) for something this basic

Comment: This time my template was done very well without jquery (just the stylesheet switcher needs it), but you're right, in the future I will focus more on learning and not just on earning. And thanks for the links :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a variable to toggle the `marginLeft`, so one click you animate left, and the other click you animate right:

```
var switched = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.switcher-header').click(function() {
        var marginLeft = switched ? '-30px' : '30px';
        switched = !switched;
        $('#switcher').animate({
            'marginLeft' : "+=" + marginLeft //moves right
        });
    });
});
```

and of course you need to include jQuery.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdx7dpeL/4/)

Comment: I added it to the whole template and it works perfectly! Thanks!